# VS2005 SP1 on Win XP crashes after loading solution with 362 projects without any error, log or trace

Tags: c++, visual-studio, crash

I am running Visual Studio 2005 on Windows XP. It crashes without any error, log or trace when I try to load the solution for our product that contains 362 projects. I don't think the size of solution (362) is a problem, because it works on my colleagues computers. There is no entry of this in Event Viewer.

Any help to locate root cause of the problem or any solution if known would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shashibhushan

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Luke for your suggestion. When I debugged using windbg.exe, it became evident that the exception was being generated at the time of loading dll related to "VMDebugger - Visual Studio Integrated Virtual Machine Debugger". I disabled it from the Add-in Manager and now the solution is being loaded successfully and working fine. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Thanks,
Shashi

Comment: I had a problem with that plugin, too; I also had to disable it.  It is part of VMware.

Answer (score 0):

Just some general thougts:

- Uninstall SP1 - i had several difficulties with it. I.e. i was unable to create a working x64 DLL using SP1
- Try again on a different machine that so far does not have Visual Studio on it. So you know wheteher its a problem of the Machine, or maybe a general Problem of Visual Studio
- Uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio.

**EDIT:**
If you started seeing these problems yesterday i would even more strongly suggest, to uninstall and reinstall VisualStudio as well as SP1. 
Did you install any new software recently?

Comment: 1. I cannot uninstall SP1, because we are using some features that we know have been fixed in SP1.
2. It works on computers of all my colleagues. In fact is used to work on my PC previously. I started seeing this problem from yesterday.
3. I already tried rebooting Windows many times and also reinstalled Visual Studio along with SP1.

Comment: I tried following steps, but still face the problem.
1. Tried opening the solution in safe mode.
2. Ensured that the .sln file is containing the projects.
3. Tried deleting the .suo as well as .ncb file.
4. Tried reinstalling VS 2005 and then SP1.
5. Tried running devenv /resetuserdata
6. The solution file (.sln) is located in a workspace created using Perforce (used for source control). Hence I was wondering if that has anything to do about this. Hence, I uninstalled Perforce client from my computer.

Comment: An observation is that it loads all the projects. While the last project is still being shown as being loaded, it crashes. I tried removing the last project. Then it crashes for the second last one (currently the last one) and so on. Looks like, the problem is seen immediately after all the projects are loaded.

Comment: Try attaching Windbg to visual studio before loading your solution; at least this way you could get a crash dump to look at and maybe send to Microsoft.  We have a solution with about 50 projects and Visual Studio has a hard time dealing with it (long load times, crashes with IntelliSense, etc); I can't even imagine a solution with 360 projects.